# Temporary objects regarding Move constructors (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

Suppose that I have a class, i.e. `class MyClass`, and I have implemented a Move constructor `MyClass::MyClass(MyClass &&rhs):ptr(rhs.ptr) {rhs.ptr=nullptr;}` for it. Moreover, `class MyClass` contains a single member attribute which is a pointer to an integer: `int* ptr;`. If I declare a vector that contains `class MyClass` objects, IOW `std::vector<MyClass> vec;`, and use `std::vector::push_back` method with an r-value such that:

```
std::vector<MyClass> vec;
vec.push_back(MyClass {5});
```

The constructor of `class MyClass` is firstly called for creating an object for `MyClass {5}`. Then the Move constructor is subsequently called and we say that we steal the resources of the "temporary" object. However, I don't get exactly which object do we steal the resources from. When the Move constructor is called, I think that a temporary object (i.e. an x-value expression) is constructed and we steal the resources from this object and give them to the first object that we have created with the constructor of `class MyClass`. Then, this x-value is destructed as soon as the Move constructor goes out of scope and we finally `push_back` the object that contains the stolen data into the vector. In a nutshell, we "move" the resources in the memory.

If a temporary object is being created inside the Move constructor, what is the advantage of the Move constructors over the Copy constructors? In the case of a Move constructor, the program creates 2 objects one of which is temporary and destructed in a short amount of time. In the case of a Copy constructor, the program creates 2 objects one of which is again destroyed as soon as the object is copied into the vector (I infer these from the number of times the constructors and destructors get called).

It might be the case that I misunderstood the procedure behind the copying and construction process for the Move and Copy constructors, however, I could not get any answers for my question from other questions on SO. They simply state that the objects are "created", "copied", and "moved", however, I would like to know the details under these processes.

Comment: `MyClass::MyClass(MyClass &&rhs) {};` does not "steal" anything. It does nothing

Comment: I meant MyClass::MyClass(MyClass &&rhs):ptr(rhs.ptr) {rhs.ptr=nullptr;}. I wanted my question to be general but you are right that I should add this to the question.

Comment: *"what is the advantage of the Move constructors over the Copy constructors?"* -- didn't you mention the advantage earlier in the question? Let's see... yes, there it is: *"we say that we steal the resources of the "temporary" object."* What more are you looking for?

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer *" I wanted my question to be general"* -- you could have achieved this by removing details instead of adding them, as in *"I have implemented a Move constructor `MyClass::MyClass(MyClass &&rhs)`"* -- skip the body, since what is relevant for that part of the text is the name. You could even shorten the name to the declaration you might see in the class definition: `MyClass(MyClass &&)`.

Comment: @JaMiT Even if we steal the resources of the temporary object, we still construct it. Isn’t this also an overhead?

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer *"Isn’t this also an overhead?"* -- Yes? In the sense that paying $10 for delivery is overhead (corresponding to the "copy" overhead), and paying $1 for gas to drive over and pick up your order is also overhead (corresponding to the "move" overhead). If you want the zero-overhead option, use `emplace_back`.

Comment: Your order of events is off. I think it does not impact the question, but I'll leave that decision up to you. The order of events is 1) the temporary object is created; 2) `push_back` is called (with the temporary object as its argument); 3) `push_back` makes space in the vector; 4) the move constructor is called to "steal" resources from the temporary to the object in the vector; 5) `push_back` ends; 6) the temporary is destroyed (at the semicolon ending the statement).

Comment: "...resources from the temporary to the object in the vector..." So there is also an object in the vector which is different from the temporary object and we steal the resources from the temporary object and put them to the object in the vector. However, where is this "object" in the vector constructed? Is its construction implicit? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253067/discussion-between-jamit-and-conventionalprogrammer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you don't understand may be how the vector uses your temporary objects for optimization. Let's do a set of tests.

```
struct Vector {
  MyClass *t;
  int size = 0;
  Vector() { t = new MyClass[4]; }
  ~Vector() { delete[] t; }
  void push_back(MyClass &&myClass) {
    t[size] = std::move(myClass);
    size++;
  }
  void push_back(const MyClass &myClass) {
    t[size] = myClass;
    size++;
  }
};
```

Then we add print information to the MyClass constructor.

```
struct MyClass {
  MyClass() { printf("I'm Constructor\n"); }
  MyClass &operator=(MyClass &&myClass) {
    printf("I'm move assignments Constructor\n");
    return *this;
  }
  MyClass &operator=(const MyClass &myClass) {
    printf("I'm copy assignments Constructor\n");
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Then we test it.

```
Vector vector;
printf("push_back()\n");
MyClass myClass;
vector.push_back(myClass);
vector.push_back(MyClass());
vector.push_back(std::move(myClass));
```

The result may be as follows:

```
...  
push_back()      
I'm Constructor
I'm copy assignments Constructor
I'm Constructor
I'm move assignments Constructor
I'm move assignments Constructor
```

As you can see from the results, the temporary object simply replaces copy assignments with move assignments. But it is not clear that move is better than copy here, so we add a dynamically allocated pointer p to MyClass, if it is large, then we can steal the memory allocated by temporary objects directly through this->p=p in move assignments, which reduces the memory allocation overhead in this process.